# JavaScript template append

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

Hi I am using jQuery Ajax to "GET" "XML" data,
and am trying to "append" the data as a "Template".

And I am trying to append the Title:

```
   <div class="btn-group" style="margin:5px">
      <img class="img-swap2" data-toggle="dropdown" src="images/drop-down-btn_2.png">
     <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
```

append the Image/Description:

```
<img src="images/toggle-on.png" class="img-swap"/>
<a class="pull-left" href="#"></a>
   <div class="media-body" style>
       <div class="media">
          <a class="pull-left" href="#">                
             <img class="media-object" src="images/Penguins.jpg"></a>
           <div class="media-body">
             <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" readonly>Description..</textarea>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Append Code:

```
var html = title + thumbnailUrl + description

var title = $(cur).find("title").text();
var thumbnailUrl = $(cur).find("thumbnailUrl").text();
var description = $(cur).find("description").text();

var $l = $mainStoryList;
$l.append(html);
```

Comment: $(cur) - what is this?

Comment: title,description,thumbnailUrl what selectors they are?

Comment: What problems, specifically, are you having?  I don't see any code trying to append anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

title,description,thumbnailUrl are **`class selectors`** means speacify with **`dot(.)`** like this

```
var title = $(cur).find(".title").text();
var thumbnailUrl = $(cur).find(".thumbnailUrl").text();
var description = $(cur).find(".description").text();
```

Suppose it is all are **`id selector`** means put **`#`** before on it

```
var title = $(cur).find("#title").text();
var thumbnailUrl = $(cur).find("#thumbnailUrl").text();
var description = $(cur).find("#description").text();
```